# Detail view button opens another detail view according to sqlite db

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, uiimageview, mkmapview

I have a sqlite db and I'm populating the table view with it. Every cell opens a detail view accordingly. In this detail view I have some buttons which will have to open other detail views, (one an image view, one a map view, one to download a pdf file) but all of these will have to show things depending on the table view row selected in the first place.
How can I do that?
Thanx

**TableVC.m**

```
#import "TableVC.h"
#import "DetailPointsVC.h"

@interface TableVC ()

@end

@implementation TableVC {
NSMutableArray *listOfTitle;
NSMutableArray *listOfImages;
}

@synthesize sendDataTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self initDatabase];
[self getPoints];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

-(void)initDatabase{
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (success)
{
    return;
}
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
 }

-(void)getPoints{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"geositidb.sqlite"];
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest";

    sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement;


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &searchStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        listOfTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        listOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
           NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 2)];
            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 10)];

            [listOfTitle addObject:title];
            [listOfImages addObject:image];

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement);
}
 }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [listOfTitle count];
}

 //Table View cell
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier =@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

    cell.textLabel.text = [listOfTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;
 }


//Detail View items
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.sendDataTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailPointsVC *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
 destViewController.dataName = [listOfTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 destViewController.dataImage = [listOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



}
}

 @end
```

**DetailPointsVC.h**

```
@interface DetailPointsVC : UIViewController
 //UILabel
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *dataLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dataName;
//UIImageView
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dataImageView;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dataImage;
```

**DetailPointsVC.m**

```
 @interface DetailPointsVC ()

 @end

 @implementation DetailPointsVC
 @synthesize dataLabel;
 @synthesize dataName;
 @synthesize dataImageView;
 @synthesize dataImage;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.dataLabel.text = dataName;
self.dataImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:dataImage];
 }
@end
```

A button on this detail view opens another view where the image should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you have the following view controllers:

```
List ---> Detail ----> Image
                  |
                  |--> Map
                  |
                  ---> PDF
```

You can just pass as many details as required to 'Detail' in the `prepareForSegue:` method of 'List', and pass them to the next view controllers when the buttons are clicked. For example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showImage"]) {
        DetailImageVC *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.dataImage = self.dataImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this on the table view.m file: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.sendDataTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
            DetailPuntiVC *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            destViewController.dataName = [listOfTitolo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
which opens the detail view according to the cell. On this detail view I've a button to open another detail view which'll have to show a pdf according to the detail view I just opened

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You are already doing the right thing then - maybe you need to pass more details from the List to the Detail? If my current answer doesn't help enough, please post more details of the relevant view controllers. It's hard to help people without seeing their code.

Comment: Framework is correct. I have: Table.m 
implementation TableVC {
NSMutableArray *listOfImages;}
listOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init;
NSString *immagine = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 10)];
in the PrepareForSegue: destViewController.dataImage = [listOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
in the detail view: property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dataImageView;
property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dataImage;
but the image shouldnt open here coz there's no image view, instead in another view (opened by a button in detail view)

Comment: @Max1980 please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31895272/edit) your question to include the code snippets. They're very hard to read in comments.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've now edited the code to make it clearer.

Comment: Just implement `prepareForSegue` in `DetailPointsVC` as well. See my updated answer.